# Can we use another database apart from MongoDB?

Tags: fiware-orion

I am using FIWARE orion using MongoDB as storage database. Are there any other database apart from MongoDB to which we can connect FIWARE orion presently?

Secondly, can FIWARE Orion be simply use for push and pull of data 'without' a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use Orion with another DB different from MongoDB or using it without DB at all.

Link: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/install/index.html
Section:

[image]